# Opencv program exits despite no ERROR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, execution

I tried to run the [Feature matching with FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) code. I am using Ms Visual C++ 2010 Express and I dont get any error while building solution

> 1>------ Build started: Project: SURF_image_matching, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  SURF_image_matching.cpp
>   1>c:\users\karthick\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\surf_image_matching\surf_image_matching\surf_image_matching.cpp(83): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
>   1>  SURF_image_matching.vcxproj -> C:\Users\KARTHICK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SURF_image_matching\Debug\SURF_image_matching.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When I run, it terminates without any output I get several lines of the following form

> 'SURF_image_matching.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'SURF_image_matching.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>
> 'SURF_image_matching.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Searchqu Toolbar\Datamngr\IEBHO.dll'
>   'SURF_image_matching.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[7592] SURF_image_matching.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: you can safely ignore the 1st 2 lines. the pdb files arent supplied with the download, meaning you can debug your code, but not the opencv-lib code. that's a warning, not an error, btw

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the compiler can see OpenCV bin directory, it can be done by one of two ways:

1. Add it to your environment `PATH` variable
2. Select your VS solution Configuration Properties > Debugging >
   Environment  set the value to

   ```
   PATH = %PATH%;C:\OpenCVX.XX\bin
   ```

Hope it helps.